# TinyB based app - Unsupported JNI version 0x00010008

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, native

I'm trying to develop a BLE based Java application and I'm using TinyB for that. After a long run in fixing issues about building the project (in particular for include directories), now I'm stuck with the following error when launching the app from Eclipse:

```
Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unsupported JNI version 0x00010008 required by /usr/local/lib/libjavatinyb.so.0.5.0.0.5.0.0.5.0
```

I'm not skilled in building libraries, so I don't know what to include in the question to help solving the issue.

Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~15.10.1-  b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

javac version

```
javac 1.8.0_91
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me!
I didn't realize that Eclipse was still using the old Java 7 environment.
Switching from Java 7 to Java 8 is always a never-ending story.......
Everything is fine now.